# manage.windowsazure.com user experience issues

Tags: azure, azure-management-portal

What am I missing that is causing my issues accessing "https://manage.windowsazure.com" or "https://portal.azure.com"

My problem is trying to access either of these sites from IE 11 on Windows 8.1.  It is running as a VM in VMWare Fusion.
If I try to open IE as a normal session and go to the portal site I get the url.  ../sigin/index and a white page, nothing else happens at all.  If I try to access the manage site I am able to get to the "all items" view but I always am shown the message "You have signed out elsewhere.  Click OK to log out from the management portal"  I can get around this by hitting escape.  I've tried deleting Temporary internet files and cookies to no avail.
If I try opening IE in a private session and go to portal.azure.com  I am currently able to get into the portal and I can get into the manage.windowsazure.com page, however the information does not load/refresh.  I.e. this morning when I logged in I could get in, and I tried to delete several of my resources.  The webpage said it was doing something, but it never seemed to process.  Logging in now, none of the resources load (just progress bars for all of them.

Now if I open these same sites in Safari on my host computer the management experience is much better, I can delete things, the pages load and refresh.

Yesterday I went to an Microsoft sponsored intro class on Azure.  The facility was also using Windows 8 and I created a new outlook.com account for the class.  I had no inexplicable issues managing Azure during the class.

Is this a hardware resource issue or the fact that we're using ADFS.  Any help is appreciated.

We are using ADFS for our Office365 logins and I'm trying to access the azure account associated with my Office365 account.  We have no noticeable issues getting into the Office365 sites.

My VM has 2 GB of RAM and is running on a MacBook Pro (2012) 2.6 GHz i7.  Suggestions are appreciated.  I really want to make Azure work for us, but it seems overly difficult.  This has been across multiple days and reboots of my computer.  I'm pretty sure along the way I have reset IE as well.

--edit I upped the VM to 4GB of RAM and no immediate changes yet.

Comment: is there any reason you access azure via IE in VM on the Mac? if Windows experience is mandatory, how about to open Azure site with FireFox in Windows VM? BTW, I do not have any trouble to use Azure by IE11+Win8.1 (no VM).

Comment: I am on a Mac to support the few Mac users we have in the company.  I do a majority of my work in the Windows VM because we're a windows shop.  I am using IE, because I figured it would provide a better experience since it's coming from the same company. I do not have firefox installed. Neither Firefox or Chrome work inside the office with our ADFS setup.  I know this and we choose not to make the change that would allow them to work.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2461628